# как "спрятать" порт при перенаправлении

Tags: nginx, apache2, httpd

задача: на одном hostname поднять несколько сервисов. Было принято решение реализовать через nginx следующим образом:
сервисы:

```
example.com/foo
example.com/bar
```

nginx по foo/bar перенаправляет на httpd виртуальные хосты на порты

```
foo -> 127.0.0.1:8000, bar -> 127.0.0.1:8001.
```

Проблема в следующем, при текущих настройках у клиента в адресе вводим example.com/foo, после отработки сервиса получаем example.com:8000/foo
Как убрать порт?
upd После ([рекомендации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1272942/369937)) конфиг упростил до

```
server {
    listen 172.16.0.10;
    server_name  example.com;

    location /foo/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

upd 2(без слэша)

```
# curl -v http://example.com/foo
*   Trying 172.16.0.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (172.16.0.10) port 80 (#0)
> GET /foo HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.14.1
< Date: Sun, 25 Apr 2021 02:27:08 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Location: http://example.com/foo/
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.1</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

upd 3(со слэшем)

```
# curl -v http://example.com/foo/
*   Trying 172.16.0.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (172.16.0.10) port 80 (#0)
> GET /foo/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.14.1
< Date: Sun, 25 Apr 2021 02:28:31 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 239
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://example.com:8000/foo
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://example.com:8000/foo">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

Comment: Хостить его на 80, или же сделать проксирование?

Comment: сделать проксирование.

Comment: `proxy_redirect off;` должно помочь

Comment: Вы посмотрите настройки своего сервиса, скорее всего он подставляет вам ссылки в таком формате.

Comment: nginx присылает редирект, но в показанном сейчас конфиге нет никакого редиректа. Где-то нестыковочка

Comment: @andreymal редирект похож на https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location *Если location задан префиксной строкой со слэшом в конце и запросы обрабатываются при помощи proxy_pass, [...] происходит специальная обработка*, но при этом в риведённом конфиге слеша нет. Я подозреваю что автор показывает не настоящий конфиг.

Comment: прошу прощения за задержку. выяснил, что разработчик приложения добавил у себя редиректы. на данный момент божится, что убрал.

Answer (score 0):

Какой-то переусложнённый конфиг со странным rewrite-ом.

Попробуйте написать проще:

```
server {
    listen 172.16.0.10;
    server_name example.com;

    location /foo/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за упрощение. Приложение работает. Но порт в адресной строке остался.

Comment: Покажите вывод `curl -v http://example.com/foo/`

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: А зачем апач делает такой странный редирект?

Comment: Покажите `curl -v http://example.com/foo` (без слеша на конце)

Comment: обновил, конф вирт.хоста
```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot /web/sites/foo/public

    <Directory /web/sites/foo/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Кажется вы показали не тот конфиг nginx который у вас на самом деле. Проверьте внимательно все слеши. Второй апдейт показывает редирект от nginx когда location заканчивается на слеш, а в вашем коде это не так